# Support other non-text filetypes in git

Tags: git, plugins, diff, file-type

Is it possible to extend git (via a plug-in) to support other filetypes which aren't based on plain ASCII files? For the sake of an example: Imagine someone write a diff program for photoshop `psd` files with [PSD.rb](http://cosmos.layervault.com/psdrb.html) to represent changes in the underlying binary `psd` file as text.

I haven't found anything on google, so perhaps some of the more in depth git hackers can answer this.

Comment: Note: diff for PSD is supported on GitHub now (June 2014): see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24251514/6309.

Comment: Note bis: diff for PSD is no longer supported on GitHub now (March 2022)... https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-22-diffing-adobe-photoshop-documents-is-no-longer-supported/

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is called **[`git difftool`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)**.
you can specify in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html) the extensions for that particular difftool to be applied.

See for instance this blog post "[Image diffs with git](http://www.akikoskinen.info/image-diffs-with-git/)" by [Aki Koskinen](http://www.akikoskinen.info/about/)

```
git config --global core.attributesfile '~/.gitattributes'

[~]$ cat .gitattributes 
*.gif diff=image
*.jpg diff=image
*.png diff=image

[~]$ git config --global diff.image.command '~/bin/git-imgdiff'

[~]$ cat ~/bin/git-imgdiff
#!/bin/sh
compare $2 $1 png:- | montage -geometry +4+4 $2 - $1 png:- | display -title "$1" -
```